# How to prepending a list before every row in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for the most efficient way to prepend all the rows in `IEnumerable<T>` A before each row in `IEnumerable<T>` B.

For example:

```
A = {A, B}
B = {1, 2, 3}
```

After prepending:

```
B = {A, B, 1, A, B, 2, A, B, 3}
```

Comment: Since you want it to work for `IEnumerable` and you're iterating over `A` multiple times there's not one solution that will be fastest in all cases - if A is lazy-loaded it will be more efficient to hydrate to a concrete collection first, which would be unnecessary if A was _already_ concrete,

Answer (score 3):

You can create a method like this one,

```
public void IEnumerable<T> PrependBeforeRow<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> A, 
    IEnumerable<T> B)
{
    foreach (var b in B)
    {
        foreach (var a in A)
        {
            yield return a;      // <-- first iterate over A and return all items
        }

        yield return b;      // <-- the yield the current item from B
    }
}
```

This is probably, the simplest way, while keeping the "deferred execution" aspect of `IEnumerable<T>`.

You potentially do use `Select`/`SelectMany` and make it a bit more succinct,

```
public void IEnumerable<T> PrependBeforeRow<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> A, 
    IEnumerable<T> B)
{
    return B.Select(b => new List<T>(A) { b }).SelectMany(ab => ab);
}
```

The only issue being that `A` will be iterated entirely every time a new `B` item is yield.

Comment: Although this is going to fail if, for example, `A` is `File.ReadLines("Foo.txt")`, because after the first time you enumerate `A` it will be at end of file. Or it could just take a really long time because every time you enumerate `A`, it has to do a database query or something. This will work fine if `A` is a reference to a concrete object, but it's potentially troublesome or even fatal if `A` is depending on deferred execution.

Comment: Well, of course, performance would depend on the data source for these `IEnumerable<T>`s.